# Windows+arrow equivalent on linux

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, windows, snap-windows

In Windows if you are in a program and press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for example the program would take up half of the left side of the screen. Extremely useful when wanting two programs to sit side by side.

<kbd>Super</kbd> key being the special key in Linux then. And the <kbd>←</kbd> being the arrow left key.

What is the Ubuntu version of this? I have no idea what this is *called* and hence my Google results have come out with no result.

Comment: @devGeek thank you! snapping was the name! I found the command: Ctrl+WIN+Left

Comment: Glad! you got it. BTW, see **nux's** answer below, will benefit your more.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can set this with CompizConfig Settings Manager

install cssm like this:

[Install CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)

Then open it up and go to setting "Window Management" ->Grid" under

[Image for selection](http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/846adc609cc369408367d703ac8597b7.png)

You can set your shortcuts.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The link seems to be broken, but you can install CompizConfig using the "Ubuntu Software" program on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can press & hold <kbd>Super</kbd> button to display keyboard shortcuts .

<kbd>Super</kbd>  is your windows <kbd>WIN</kbd> button .